# Какая разница между <?> и <? extends Object>?

Tags: java

Как я понял, вместо  подставить можно любой тип (кроме примитивов), зачем тогда есть ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<?>` и `<? extends Object>` являются синонимами, как и ожидается, но есть несколько случаев с дженериками, где `extends Object` фактически не является избыточным. Например, `<T extends Object & Foo>` приведет к тому, что `T` станет объектом при стирании, тогда как с `<T extends Foo>` он станет `Foo` при стирании. (Это может иметь значение, если вы пытаетесь сохранить совместимость с API-интерфейсом предварительного генерации, который использовал Object).

(Здесь: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/convert.html; объясняется, почему класс `java.util.Collections` JDK имеет метод с этой сигнатурой:

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

Сссылка на источник SO: [What's the difference between `<?>` and `<? extends Object>` in Java Generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055497/5275890)

Answer (score 2):

```
<? extends T>
```

- позволяет сделать дженериком любой класс дочерний от класса T, при этом запрещает классы родителей

`ArrayList<? extends Number>` ... и тд. можем в реализации записать как `<Integer>`, но не сможем как `<Object>`

```
<? super T>
```

- позволяет сделать дженериком любой класс являющийся родителем классу T вплоть до Object, запрещая классы потомков

`ArrayList<? super Number>` ... и тд. можем в реализации записать как `<Object>`, но не сможем как `<Integer>`

Вся красота полиморфизма.

Answer (score 1):

По сути, разницы нет. Но по дефолту любой класс наследуется от `Object` и `? extends Object` можно не писать.